Sheets - Queries and cross referencing multiple sheets
I have a Query Column. I am trying to take the return value for that cell, see if it contains a string, and pull the value from column B where the query matches on column A, but only if another column is blank. Everything is a string.
EX:
Sheet 1: StaticReport



Column A




query



Sheet 2: RollingLog



Data
Other Data




condensed data
Other Data



Sheet 3: StaticDB



CodeList
Expanded Info




Code
explanation of the code



How I have been attempting to do this:
=QUERY({RollingLog!$A2:B;StaticDB!A2:B},"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 LIKE Col3"&if(Col2=""))
Trying to compare Data on RollingLog to CodeList on StaticDB and returning Expanded from StaticDB where Code is contained within Data, but only for rows where Other Data is blank.
I'm probably approaching this wrong, any ideas?

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

It's three sheets. If RollingLog!A1 = ABC-XYZ-123, StaticDB!A1 = XYZ, and StaticDB!B1 = "Examine Your Zipper": the Query needs to look up the value from StaticDB!B1, using a partial value from RollingLog!A1, but only if RollingLog!B1 is not empty. StaticDB is a table containing all valid Codes.

@MikeOehler What you are trying to do with if(Col2="")? if(Col2="") will not work with QUERY() function. What problem are you facing with your current formula?

It was probably a bad example I saw suggesting I could do this.
=QUERY({RollingLog!$A2:B;StaticDB!A2:B},"SELECT Col4 WHERE Col1 LIKE Col3 AND Col2 is Null))
is probably more proper.
Issue is I'm trying to figure out how to take a partial value from one sheet, do a lookup on a different sheet, and have a cell from that row move over to a third sheet as part of a Query statement.

Hi! Can you provide a sample sheet? Showing your data looks like, and I was hoping you can provide a manually inputted expected result to give more clarification with your requirements. It would clarify which partial parts were you referring to.

The query is flawed, 1) the number of rows in the "StaticDB" MUST be the same as "RollingLog". Perhaps this is true in your sample, but it might not be true in real life. 2) As written, it will only search for a match in the equivalent row of "StaticDB". Again, that works in the sample, but my guess is that you are looking for a match in ANY row of "StaticDB".

Try this formula in cell B2 of "StaticReport" where Cell A2 contains the value of RollingLog!A1.

=query(
let(frag ,A2,
map(
  query({StaticDB!A1:B},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",),
  query({StaticDB!A1:B},"select Col2 where Col1 is not null",),
lambda(s,i,if(regexmatch(frag,s),i,)))
),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",)

Logic

opening query is only to remove blank rows from the lambda result. (There is probably, almost certainly, a better way to do this.)
let - allows definition of the value from RollingLog!A1
map - two arrays are defined using query, one each for "CodeList" and "Expanded Info"
lambda

tests for regexmatch of RollingLogA1 with each of the values in "CodeList"
where TRUE, returns the corresponding value for "Expanded Info"



h/t @ninjagecko for Multiple regex matches in Google Sheets formula

Sample - StaticReport


Sample - StaticDB

